# Visual Studio Project: Duplicated Project Guids

Tags: visual-studio, project, guid

I got some projects from someone else. (He converted this projects)
It seems that he copy&pasted the projectfiles from my demo-project.

Now, all the converted projects have the same project GUID. This is definitely not good.
**But what might happen if some projects have the same GUID?**
Can there be errors in TFS or somethere else?

And how can i fix that? The simplest solution is to replace the duplicated Guids with a newly created Guid (Create GUID-Tool in VS or via Guid.NewGuid())
But i think it is not so easy. This guids might be referenced from somethere else.

**What uses the project Guid? I know it is used in the solution file. And somethere else?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Projects in a solution are defined like so:

```
Project("{project type GUID}") = "<Project name>", "<project file location>", "{<Unique project GUID>}"
EndProject
```

The `project type GUID` will be the same for all projects, whilst the `unique project GUID` needs to be unique per project.

This is important since it is used in the solution file to indicate build configurations.

You 'could' theoretically replace the GUID's yourself, but the best approach would be to remove the projects from the solution and add them again.

Comment: Yes. The duplicated GUID is the (normally) unique GUID. The projects are in different solutions, but i am concerned that this could have an impact on other things. (Especially if i replace the duplicated GUIDs manually) I cant exlude the possibility that this change harm something else. Is this unique GUID used by something other than solutions?

Comment: No, the unique GUID only makes sense in the context of a given solution.  It's sole purpose is to map certain settings to a project independently of the project name.

It is therefore not a problem to have projects in different solutions sharing the same GUID.

Comment: until you attempt to install both projects on the same machine, and the GUIDs collide....